# Why does it require schema name before the table name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on HR schema,
I am trying to run a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

But it says

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

while `SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;` Retrieves data.

Comment: Because the `HR` schema isn't your default schema? The whole point of schemas is to provide separate namespaces in which you can have identically named tables. If they weren't then involved in name resolution like this, how would you envisage things working when there are multiple `EMPLOYEES` tables in multiple schemas?

Comment: may be , i tried : 
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=HR;
 it enabled me to select from the table without using schema name
but it ends when i close the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**why does it requires schema name before table name?**

if the table is not in same schema with your current user (connected user) you need to prefix schema name in order to access table.

or alternatively, your target table need to have [public] synonym